# Deleting a Rule according to the first element

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of rules. Among them, I want to delete those rules which have first elements already shown up earlier. Following is a working example.

```
A = {1->2, 1->3, 2->5, 3->4, 4->1, 3->5};
```

Here, I want `1->3` to be deleted as `1` has already shown up in first elements `1->2`. `2->5` should remain as `2` has not taken first position in earlier elements. So should `3->4` and `4->1`.
The last element 3->5 should be deleted as `3` is taken already by `3->4`. Hence the output should be

```
{1->2, 2->5, 3->4, 4->1}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DeleteDuplicates[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 3 -> 5}, First[#1] == First[#2] &]
```

Answer (score 8):

[`DeleteDuplicatesBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicatesBy.html) has better algorithmic complexity than [`DeleteDuplicates`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html) with a custom comparison function.

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[A, First]
(* {1 -> 2, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1} *)
```